# How to get SGD to reach global optimal point in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, optimization, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am trying to write a tool which involves implementing logistic regression. With the batch gradient descent method, the convergence is guaranteed as it is a convex problem. However, I find that with the stochastic gradient decent method  typically converges to some random points (i.e., not very close to the minimum point resulted from the batch method). I have tried different ways of decreasing the learning rate, and different starting points of weights. However, the performance (e.g., accuracy, precision/recall, ...) are comparable (to the batch method).

I understand that this is possible, since SGD (stochastic gradient descent) uses an approximation to the real cost each step. I guess this matters since otherwise the interpretation of the weights would not make much sense even the accuracy is comparable.

- Does it matter that SGD uses an approximation the real cost at each step?
- If it matters, how can it be made to converge or get close to the global optimal point?

Comment: A guess, assuming you're minimizing NLL: the surface has flat troughs. Did you normalize your data?